# 'module' does not support the buffer interface

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

```
from PIL import Image, ImageSequence
import glob
from images2gif import writeGif

fn0 = glob.glob('*.jpg')
im = [Image.open(filename) for filename in fn0]

writeGif('1.gif', im, duration=0.1 )
#file "images2gif.py" line 578
#gifWriter.writeGifToFile(fp,images,duration,loops,xy,dispose)
#file "images2gif.py" line 439
#fp.write(globalPalette)
#ERROR: 'module' does not support the buffer interface
```

I just used module images2gif on my WinPython, and I've installed imageio before it. But I don't know where this error comes from. I am using the latest images2gif module from :
**https://code.google.com/p/visvis/source/browse/vvmovie/images2gif.py**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

writeGif probably wants an open, writable file (or something that acts like it), rather than a string representing the name of a file.

Maybe something like this will work better?

```
with open('1.gif') as fp:
    writeGif(fp, im, duration=0.1 )
```

Comment: The idea is good. But I've read many examples and there is no need to create a file and then write to it. However, I tried this one but it didn't work. Thanks.